# Read the count of a U-SQL Table as a scalar value?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I want to save a U-SQL table to a csv file only if it is non-empty. However, I am not sure how to get the count of the table as a scalar value so that I can use an IF condition. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We do not provide a way to do a dynamic IF expression at this point. That means today, you always create an empty file.

You can check in U-SQL with the [`FILE.LENGTH`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt807524.aspx) intrinsic function if a file is empty and then for example skip the processing in later scripts.

If you feel that you need the ability to not output the file if you have an empty rowset, please file a feature request at http://aka.ms/adlfeedback.

Thanks
Michael

PS: My apologies for the late reply, but I am catching up from my summer travels :)